# array_merge & in_array not what I need

Tags: php

I have an array like this;

```
$array = array(
     array('id' => 1, 'amount' => 104, 
     array('id' => 46, 'amount' => 200,
     array('id' => 1004, 'amount' => 200
);
```

and another array like this;

```
$array2 = array(
     array('id' => 206, 'amount' => 50, 
     array('id' => 1, 'amount' => 96,
     array('id' => 88, 'amount' => 2
);
```

How to I add check if the 'id' in array2 exists in $array. If it does at the 'amount' of $array2 to $array, if it doesn't exist append the id and amount onto the end of $array. I want the output result to look like this:

```
array {
     [0] id = 1  amount = 200
     [1] id = 46 amount = 200
     [2] id = 1004 amount = 200
     [3] id = 206 amount = 50
     [4] id = 88 amount = 2
}
```

I have tried using array_merge and in_array but can't seem to get my head around it working.

Comment: are they nested or have you missed the closing `)` to the child arrays?

Comment: I have just missed them. Typed them on on here didn't copy & paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try somthing like this :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $found = false ;
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($value2['id'] == $value['id']) {
            $array2[$key2]['amount'] += $value['amount'];
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $array2[] = $value ;
    }
}

print_r($array2);
```

outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [amount] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [amount] => 200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 88
            [amount] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [amount] => 200
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1004
            [amount] => 200
        )

)
```

---

**EDIT** After comments, updated code with a final check to remove duplicated rows :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $found = false ;
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($value2['id'] == $value['id']) {
            $array2[$key2]['amount'] += $value['amount'];
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $array2[] = $value ;
    }
}


$final = [];
foreach ($array2 as $key1 => $value) {
    $found = false ;
    foreach ($final as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($value2['id'] == $value['id']) {
            $final[$key2]['amount'] += $value['amount'];
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $final[] = $value ;
    }
}

var_dump($final) ;
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Except if I have multiple IDs the same in $array2 they just append onto the end of $array instead of stacking

Comment: @NathanMayes Yes. Did the anwser helps you ? I'll update my anwser.